# Static Form twitter-bootstrap and Xampp

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, static, xampp

I have a static form whose code is bellow. Basically I would like to style it with Twitter-bootstrap. Thus I was wondering how to implement it under Xampp. I have placed the bootstrap folder under Xammp/htdocs/MyLocalHostWebsiteFolderName/bootstrap, added a class to the form HTML code but bootstrap was not compiled with the form.

cAN YOU HELP ME BREATH SOME LIFE IN THAT BEATEN UP CODE?

```
<html>
<head>   
    <title>Limited Sampling Strategies for AUC estimation</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".msg_body").hide();
            $(".msg_head").click(function(){
                $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(600);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>      
<body>
<center>
<form action="form.php" class="form-horizontal" target="results" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post'>
<h1>Limited Sampling Strategies for AUC estimation</h1>

<table border=0>
<tr valign="top">
<td>
<table border=1>
    <caption>Data</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Concentrations</th>
        <td> <input type="file" name="concentrations" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Times</th>
        <td> <input type="file" name="times" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <th>Covariates</th>
        <td> <input type="file" name="covariates" size="20"></td>   
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
</td>

</table>

</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "cAN YOU HELP ME BREATH SOME LIFE IN THAT BEATEN UP CODE?" This is not exactly a question now is it? Try to write a meaningful question (obviously closely related to the title of your post). Also your CapsLock might be broken. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. The form code should call bootstrap library before the HTML code otherwise the CSS classes are not recognized. Putting your form HTML code in the bootstrap folder alone is not enough. The structure goes like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

          <head>
            <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
          </head>
          <body>
        <center>
        <form class="form-inline" action="form.php" target="results" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post'>

        </form>
        </center>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>

        </html>
```